# Prevent class member name obfuscation by ProGuard

Tags: java, android, proguard, obfuscation

I have my class `ClassMultiPoint` with subclasses.

```
public class ClassMultiPoints
 {
   public String message;
   public List<ClassPoints> data;

   public class ClassPoints
    {
      public String id;
      public List<ClassPoint> points;
      public class ClassPoint
       {
         public String speed;
         public String bearing;
       }
    }
 }
```

I will get value of object `oPoints` from parse `GSON`:

`oPoints = gson.fromJson( jsonString, ClassMultiPoints.class);`

I try use `oPoints.message`.

When I run my application without `proguard` app run success.
When I run my app with `proguard` my app crash.

I think problem is: `proguard` rename attribute `'oPoints.message'` of my class to short `'a'`.

I try keep the names of the methods and attributes is constant, but `proguard` rename its:

`proguard.cfg:`

```
-injars      bin/classes
-injars      libs
-outjars     bin/classes-processed.jar
-dontpreverify
-repackageclasses ''
-allowaccessmodification
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-optimizationpasses 5
-printmapping map.txt
-flattenpackagehierarchy

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.MapActivity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider

-libraryjars  libs/commons-io-2.2.jar
-libraryjars  libs/ftp4j-1.7.1.jar
-libraryjars  libs/gson-2.2.2.jar

-keep public class org.apache.commons.io.**
-keep public class it.sauronsoftware.ftp4j.**
-keep public class com.google.gson.**

-keep public class com.mypackagename.ActivityMonitor$*

-keep public class * extends android.view.View {
    public <init>(android.content.Context);
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
    public void set*(...);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

-keepclassmembers class * extends android.content.Context {
   public void *(android.view.View);
   public void *(android.view.MenuItem);
}

-keepclassmembers class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
    static android.os.Parcelable$Creator CREATOR;
}

-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
    public static <fields>;
}
```

What is right way to keep names of the methods and attributes of the my one (static) class?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Thanks Waqas!

I find solution for my case:

```
-optimizationpasses 5
-dump class_files.txt
-printseeds seeds.txt
-printusage unused.txt
-printmapping mapping.txt
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging*/
-allowaccessmodification
-repackageclasses ''

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.MapActivity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider

-libraryjars  libs/commons-io-2.2.jar
-libraryjars  libs/gson-2.2.2.jar
-keep public class org.apache.commons.io.**
-keep public class com.google.gson.**
-keep public class com.google.gson.** {public private protected *;}

##---------------Begin: proguard configuration for Gson ----------
-keepattributes *Annotation*,Signature
-keep class com.mypackage.ActivityMonitor.ClassMultiPoints.** { *; }
-keep public class com.mypackage.ActivityMonitor$ClassMultiPoints     { public protected *; }
-keep public class com.mypackage.ActivityMonitor$ClassMultiPoints$ClassPoints { public protected *; }
-keep public class com.mypackage.ActivityMonitor$ClassMultiPoints$ClassPoints$ClassPoint { public protected *; }
# To support Enum type of class members
-keepclassmembers enum * { *; } 
##---------------End: proguard configuration for Gson ----------
```

Also I don't use `@SerializedName("message")` in my class, aboved config work fine without serialization.

Comment: @iDroid Explorer I use apkTool to test the release apk but obfuscation did not work for me it did not rename the classes

Comment: This settings allow NOT obfuscate the code. Are you need obfuscate code?

Comment: yes this code is not obfuscate or I am testing wrong release apk

Answer (score 76):

If you dont want your class members to be obfuscated then use `SerializedName` annotation provided by Gson. For example:

```
public class ClassMultiPoints
{
   @SerializedName("message")
   public String message;
   @SerializedName("data")
   public List<ClassPoints> data;

   ...

}
```

Moreover, make sure you do add proper proguard configuration for Gson library too. For example:

```
##---------------Begin: proguard configuration for Gson ----------
# Gson uses generic type information stored in a class file when working with
#fields. Proguard removes such information by default, so configure it to keep
#all of it.
-keepattributes Signature

# For using GSON @Expose annotation
-keepattributes *Annotation*

# Gson specific classes
-keep class sun.misc.Unsafe { *; }
#-keep class com.google.gson.stream.** { *; }

# Application classes that will be serialized/deserialized over Gson
-keep class com.google.gson.examples.android.model.** { *; }

##---------------End: proguard configuration for Gson ----------
```

For more info read [this](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/source/browse/trunk/examples/android-proguard-example/proguard.cfg).

Comment: -keep class com.google.gson.examples.android.model.** { *; } it works for me but when i applied reverse engg on apk, i got all the model classes with not change in members, it breaks the security purpose, isn't there any other option, we can obfuscate model too ?

Comment: are you using `@SerializedName` annotation on top of your class members? because if you do then you don't need to bypass custom class obfuscation in proguard config like you are doing with `com.google.gson.examples.android.model.** { *; }`.

Comment: no, actually i wanted to obfuscate it. but now i realized that if the fields names change, then they won't match json key, so the gson could not parse it.

Comment: exactly... and that's why we need to use **@SerializedName**

Comment: Is this option available for the whole class?

Comment: @iLoveUnicorns for that you need to tweak the **proguard** config to ignore obfuscating the entire class.

Comment: I don´t know if it really matters, but in general using Annotations with Runtime Policy on Android can be a performance issue. I would recommend using the -keep options of Proguard instead

Answer (score 29):

I also found I need to `-keepclassmembers` when using Dexguard's optimise option. Without this several of my model objects failed to deserialise

```
##---------------Begin: proguard configuration for Gson  ----------
# Gson uses generic type information stored in a class file when working with fields. Proguard
# removes such information by default, so configure it to keep all of it.
-keepattributes Signature

# For using GSON @Expose annotation
-keepattributes *Annotation*

# Application classes that will be serialized/deserialized over Gson, keepclassmembers
-keep class com.myapp.model.** { *; }
-keepclassmembers class com.myapp.model.** { *; }
```

Comment: special thanks for `-keepclassmembers class com.myapp.model.** { *; }`. despite of I am using jackson lib rather than gson, that line helped me! Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

If you use the `@Expose` annotation like I do, you can tell ProGuard to keep any field annotated with it:

```
# keep anything annotated with @Expose
-keepclassmembers public class * {
    @com.google.gson.annotations.Expose *;
}
# Also keep classes that @Expose everything
-keep @com.google.gson.annotations.Expose public class *
```

Comment: According to GSON javadoc @Expose can target fields only. So second instruction seems useless

Answer (score 6):

To exclude your class from obfuscation, Keep the attributes of InnerClasses, keep your class and keep the class members of the class eg.

```
-keepattributes InnerClasses
 -keep class com.yourproject.YourClass**
 -keepclassmembers class com.yourproject.YourClass** {
    *;
 }
```

For more information http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html

Answer (score 6):

There is a built-in `@Keep` annotation that you use, please refer this [link](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code.html#keep-code)

Answer (score 1):

Proguard 6.1 cannot handle interfaces with generics in a library. See the bug report here:
https://sourceforge.net/p/proguard/bugs/765/

Answer (score 1):

You can skip obfuscation in all Request type classes

```
open class Request
data class Example(val name: String) : Request()
```

### proguard-rules.pro

```
-keepclassmembers class * extends <your-package-name>.util.ws.Request { *; }
```

GL

Answer (score 1):

This thread has amazing answers already, however do not forget to add

```
-keep public class * extends java.lang.Exception
```

otherwise, all the crashes will be obfuscated when you see them on firebase.

See official docs here : https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-deobfuscated-reports?platform=android