# How to not obfuscate android code when there is an interface in class?

Tags: android, proguard

I have a class that has an Interface.

```
class A {
    public interface B {
    }
}
```

Another class will use this interface

```
B h = new B(){ };
```

But after I've obfuscated the interface doesn't work.
My Proguard:

```
-keep interface A$B{*;}
```

Comment: Are you using ProGuard? If yes, add a tag.

Comment: You need use tag "-keep" like in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15476315/how-keep-my-class-from-obfuscate-by-proguard.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you use proguard:
You need use tag "-keep" like in this post:
[How keep my class from obfuscate by proguard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15476315/how-keep-my-class-from-obfuscate-by-proguard).
Also you need read this article: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html#configuring
Regards Dzmitry