# Testing release and proguarded version of Android app - NoSuchMethodError

Tags: android, proguard, android-gradle-plugin, android-testing, android-espresso

I'm trying to test release build of Android app with Proguard turned on. I've created additional Proguard rules file for test dependencies which is included in the release rules file.

```
-keep class android.test.** { *; }
-dontwarn android.test.**

# Reuse the release ProGuard mapping
-applymapping proguard.map
-dontshrink
-dontoptimize
```

Everything compiles fine but it fails at runtime.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.test.AndroidTestRunner.addTestListener
    at com.google.android.apps.common.testing.testrunner.GoogleInstrumentationTestRunner.start(ProGuard:135)
    at com.google.android.apps.common.testing.testrunner.GoogleInstrumentationTestRunner$BridgeTestRunner.start(ProGuard:249)
    at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onCreate(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:389)
    at com.google.android.apps.common.testing.testrunner.GoogleInstrumentationTestRunner.onCreate(ProGuard:114)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4702)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:172)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1362)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5586)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I'm using Espresso for testing, the instrumentation runner is defined in `build.gradle`

```
defaultConfig {
    testApplicationId 'package.name.test'
    testInstrumentationRunner 'com.google.android.apps.common.testing.testrunner.GoogleInstrumentationTestRunner'
}
```

Any chance to run tests for proguarded release build? I've found [topic](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/adt-dev/bsj0pTbJlaA) back from May and it looks like it's impossible. For me it looks like it's just wrong Proguard configuration (missing method), but the line `-keep class android.test.** { *; }` should fix such issue. Am I missing something?

Comment: Try use my answer in another question http://stackoverflow.com/a/15477898/1665964

Answer (score 0):

Im trying to **help** Sir.

instead of that

```
-keep class android.test.** { *; } 
-dontwarn android.test.**
```

add this to it

```
-keep class android.test.** { *; }
-keep class junit.** { *; }
-dontwarn android.test.**
-dontwarn junit.**
```

actually this is a hard "guess-a-code" hope it helps

Comment: No this is not an issue. It fails at runtime with `NoSuchMethodError` at `android.test.AndroidTestRunner.addTestListener`, so your solution doesn't solve the problem.